# Changing emission light overtime Blender 2.8

Tags: light

[image]Alrighty, so I have my short little animation finished except for one thing. I can't figure out how to lower the emission light over time in separate frames.

Answer (score 1):

Hover your mouse over the emission strength and hit <kbd>I</kbd>. The property will turn yellow, meaning that you created a keyframe. Then go to a different frame, change the strength and it will turn green (meaning no keyframe) then hit <kbd>I</kbd> again hovering over that strength bar. It will turn yellow and you've got yourself a basic strength changing emission shader.

Note that this works for most properties in blender. That is how you can make transformations over time.

Comment: minecraft all the way!!!

Comment: Thank you! I just started learning this kind of stuff 2 days ago so this is all foreign to me xD